# PHP Delete User Script

Tags: php, web, delete-row

I have created this script called urmusers.php, however I get an unexpected end of file error. I am a noobie to PHP and just started learning it recently. Could anyone please look at my code and tell me what is wrong with it? I would greatly appreciate it. I also understand that mysql_* is depreciated but for the purpose of my little project it does not matter as this will not be used in a live environment but for testing purposes only.

The scrip is as follows:

```
<?php

$mysql_hostname = "localhost";
$mysql_user = "root";
$mysql_password = "newman13";
$mysql_database = "ninjaz_gaming";
$prefix = "";
$bd = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or die("Could not connect database");
mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $bd) or die("Could not select database");

$id = get_post('id');
$name = get_post('name');
$email = get_post('email');
$ircts3 = get_post('ircts3');
$game = get_post('game');

if (isset($_POST['delete']) && $id != "")
{
$query = "DELETE FROM Users WHERE id='$id'";

if (!mysql_query($query, $bd))
{
echo "DELETE failed: $query<br />" .
mysql_error() . "<br /><br />";
}
else
{
for ($j = 0 ; $j < $rows ; ++$j)
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
echo <<<_END
<pre>
Id $row[0]
Name $row[9]
Email $row[3]
IRCTS3 $row[6]
Fav Game $row[7]
</pre> 
}
<form action="urmuser.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="delete" value="yes" />
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="$row[0]" />
<input type="submit" value="DELETE USER" /></form>
_END;

}
mysql_close($bd);
function get_post($var)
{
return mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$var]);
}
?>
```

Comment: Deleting from the database is bad practice, you should append a number to a column name which wont be indexed when searching

Comment: As I have said this is a small project, and am not so much worried about little stuff like that.

Answer (score 1):

**You need to indent your code!**

You are missing the opening curly-brace `{` for the if statement on line 21.

You also need to close your PHP tags (`?>`) to put HTML there, otherwise PHP will try to parse it.
For example:

```
<pre>
    <?php
      $blah = "a";
      echo($blah);
    ?>
</pre>
    <?php
      ...
```

Comment: or: `echo '<pre>$blah</pre>';`

Comment: He is using Heredoc syntax `echo <<<_END
<pre> .... _END;` -http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: Didn't help so I switched it back. Edited my code a bit but still getting the same error.

Comment: Don't switch it back. The thing with PHP is, having one problem stops you from seeing many others. You have *many* problems. Another one being that your for loop closing bracket is *inside* your `echo` Heredoc block.

Answer (score 0):

You are not closing your `for ($j = 0 ; $j < $rows ; ++$j)` as your closing curly-bracket is inside your [Heredoc syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) `echo <<<_END <pre> .... _END;` so it is not being parsed correctly

```
for ($j = 0 ; $j < $rows ; ++$j)
{
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
echo <<<_END
<pre>
Id $row[0]
Name $row[9]
Email $row[3]
IRCTS3 $row[6]
Fav Game $row[7]
</pre> 
}   // This one here is not being parsed as a php end curly-bracket, move it to below
<form action="urmuser.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="delete" value="yes" />
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="$row[0]" />
<input type="submit" value="DELETE USER" /></form>
_END;
// move it to here
```

Need to move it to after `_END;`